# file_get_contents (and wget) very slow

Tags: php, linux, performance, wget

I'm using the google text to speech api, but for some reason it's being really slow when I connect to it via php or command line.

I'm doing this:

```
$this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}");
```

Where $text is just a urlencoded string.

I've also tried doing it via wget on the command line:

```
wget http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=test
```

Either way takes about 20 seconds or more. Via php it does eventually get the contents and add them to a new file on my server as I want it to. Via wget it times the connection out.

However, if I just go to that url in the browser, it's pretty much instant.

Could anyone shed any light on why this might be occuring?

Thanks.

Comment: could try curl() but its probably just the sites bandwidth

Comment: Can you add some more context? What kind of a machine is this on? Is it all on the same machine? How is it connected to the Internet? etc.

Comment: It's a linux machine, but the same things happens on my windows development machine.

Comment: Actually it doesn't happen on the windows one, that's pretty much instant as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort this out now, this is what I ended up doing and now it's only taking a few seconds:

```
$header=array("Content-Type: audio/mpeg"); 
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        $this->mp3data = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's due to how Google parses robots. You need to spoof the User-Agent headers to pretend to be a computer.

Some info on how to go about this would be here:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php%20curl%20spoof%20user%20agent